How quickly can the knight be trapped?
A Chess knight is placed on an infinite chessboard. If it cannot move to a square previously visited, how can you make it unable to move in as few moves as possible?
Clarifications:
The chessboard is infinite in all directions.
“Squares previously visited” include the square the knight was initially on plus all squares that the knight has moved to.

Attribution:  Yoshiyuki Kotani

Minimum number is

 15!


Why is this minimum?

 The number of squares that need to be cut off for the knight is 8 and they need to be the 7 green and 1 orange squares shown in the diagram. If the knight could move directly from the orange to purple square thus forming the prison the minimum it would take is 8 moves. The 8 squares cannot be formed by the knights jumping directly to them from another green square so the minimum number of additional moves has to be 7!


+1 Nice diagram!
